# KDL problem with cmake after complete removal

Tags: ros, kdl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have removed all the **orocos-kdl** files from ubuntu by `sudo rm -rf $ (locate orocos-kdl)`,

then I have followed the installation instructions and installed [orocos-kdl](https://github.com/orocos/orocos_kinematics_dynamics) again,

and installed `kdl-parser` using `sudo apt install ros-noetic-kdl-parser`,

now I have the following error when I try to build my workspace (which includes **industrial_trajectory_filters**):

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/kdl_parser/cmake/kdl_parserConfig.cmake:113 (message):
Project 'kdl_parser' specifies
'/usr/share/orocos_kdl/cmake/../../../include' as an include dir, which is
not found.  It does neither exist as an absolute directory nor in
'${{prefix}}//usr/share/orocos_kdl/cmake/../../../include'.  Check the issue
tracker 'https://github.com/ros/kdl_parser/issues' and consider creating a
ticket if the problem has not been reported yet.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389078/kdl-problem-with-cmake-after-complete-removal/) by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2021-10-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-21**:\

> I have removed all the **orocos-kdl** files from ubuntu by `sudo rm -rf $ (locate orocos-kdl)`,

why?

Doing this on a system with a package manager (I assume you're running Ubuntu, which uses `apt`) is a really bad idea.

**Comment by [bhomaidan](https://answers.ros.org/users/71460/bhomaidan/) on 2021-10-21**:
@gvdhoorn indeed a bad idea, I did it because I was getting a warning while building my catkin space (KTH-RPL repo) about this library that CMake can't see it since it's hidden, so I have decided to delete everything and reinstall the library again, but instead of the gentle warning, I'm getting an error says:

```
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/kdl_parser/cmake/kdl_parserConfig.cmake:113 (message):
  Project 'kdl_parser' specifies
  '/usr/share/orocos_kdl/cmake/../../../include' as an include dir, which is
  not found.  It does neither exist as an absolute directory nor in
  '${{prefix}}//usr/share/orocos_kdl/cmake/../../../include'.  Check the issue
  tracker 'https://github.com/ros/kdl_parser/issues' and consider creating a
  ticket if the problem has not been reported yet.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's a bad idea to install the latest kdl from github source, because that is going to break your `noetic` packages. What you should do is 1) remove the new files you installed, 2) reinstall the **development** package from the ubuntu repository:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall liborocos-kdl-dev
```

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1